# Snyk server can be installed in a machine without internet?

Tags: snyk

I have been using sonarqube and now i want to use snyk but dont know if it is possible to install it in an machine locally and without internet access.

Snyk server can be install in an local machine and without internet access?

Answer (score 1):

Snyk is primarily a SaaS solution; as such no full on-premise instance as you stated is available.

We have some public documentation https://snyk.io/platform/deployment-options/ and you if data residency or source code transfer is a concern, take a look at https://docs.snyk.io/scan-application-code/snyk-code/deployment-options/snyk-code-local-engine.

PS: I work for Snyk.

Comment: Second link no longer works btw